# How to open the start menu in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am new to computers. I have got a new Windows 10, how do I open the start menu? I really want to use my computer, but I can't figure how to open Microsoft Edge. Thanks!

Comment: Seriously ?? Is this a joke...you know how to open a browser and ask a question on superuser but you don't know how to open MS Edge and click the start menu !! which is at the same place since 2 or 3 decades !!

Comment: @Elmo The OP probably asked this question on another computer.

Comment: @facepalm42 That makes me face palm :D no offence intended...but why to ask such a question here (and then wait for replies) rather than search on google which gives the very first result as this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028294/windows-open-the-start-menu

Comment: @Elmo Maybe the OP can't access any search engine etc but can access this site?

Comment: @facepalm42 yeah you are right.

Comment: @facepalm42 Yes I have used a different computer to ask this question, I've used Edge to install Chrome now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a keyboard with a Windows key (near the space bar, looks like a window with four panes), tap it, and the menu should open.  This thing used to be called the Start Menu, and you can accomplish all the things that the Start Menu could do, plus more.

As of October 2019, there were recent issues with a update that broke the Windows menu, but I don't believe that's the issue for you.

Answer (score 3):

**Start Menu:**

<kbd>Windows</kbd>

**Quick Access Menu:**

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: I don't see a key with the Windows word on it on my keyboard.

Comment: It doesn't have the actual word on it, just the Windows logo. https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=windows+key

Answer (score 2):

Click on Start (lower left Windows square icon) and you should see Icons fly out to the right. Edge is or should be one of the Icons.  If not, scroll down the alphabetic list to the left for Microsoft Edge (and anything else you need). This is a standard method for Windows 10 (Non Tablet Mode)